# Navigation drawer Menu list item not updating programmaticaly

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have been working on an Android Project.I have a `setting` `activity`, where if i tick an option A, then the `navigation drawer` should `show` option `A` and when I don't tick, it shouldn't. The state of the tick button is saved in `shared preferences`.

How do I make the `navigation drawer` to check the value in `shared preferences` to decide whether to show or not to show the item `A`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing that with two different xml files. In xml files set id for the groups then in your activities `onResume` remove each groups with this code:

```
navigationView.getMenu().removeGroup(R.id.first_group);
```

Then check for the shared preferences tick state and with a `if` statement do this:

```
if (tick) {    
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.drawer_tick);
} else {
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.drawer_nottick);
}
```